# ¿Cómo listar solo unidades DVD y ver su información?

Tags: c#

Quiero hacer un programa en consola C#, en el cual me muestre cuantas hay y su información. Solo quiero que me muestre unidades de discos DVD, aunque sean SATA, IDE o por USB.

Por ejemplo:
**Unidad F:

Etiqueta de volumen :       58 Fotos 2020
Tamaño total de la unidad:  4,26 GB.**

**Unidad G:

Etiqueta de volumen :       Visual
Tamaño total de la unidad:  3,09 GB.**

Quiero hacerlo así y ya está.
El ejemplo que he visto te cuenta todas las unidades como indica abajo y no me interesa.

```
    using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Informacion_lector_Consola_01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region Configuración ventana.
            // Título de la ventana.
            Console.Title = "Información lector.";

            // Tamaño de la ventana, x, y.
            Console.SetWindowSize(80, 35);

            // Color de fondo.
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            // Color de las letras.
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

            // Limpiar pantalla y dejarlo todo en color de fondo.
            Console.Clear();

            // Visible el cursor.
            Console.CursorVisible = true;
            #endregion

            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unidad {0}", d.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("  Tipo de unidad:                 {0}", d.DriveType);
                if (d.IsReady == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  Etiqueta de volumen :       {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Sistema de archivo:         {0}", d.DriveFormat);
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "  Espacio disponible para el usuario actual:{0, 15} bytes",
                        d.AvailableFreeSpace);

                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "  Espacio total disponible:                 {0, 15} bytes",
                        d.TotalFreeSpace);

                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "  Tamaño total de la unidad:                {0, 15} bytes ",
                        d.TotalSize);
                }
            }

            // Pulse cualquier tecla para continuar.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de **Linq** y poner lo siguiente:

```
var allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d => d.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom);
```

De esta forma obtienes todos los dispositivos y mediante el **operador Where** filtras solamente por el tipo de dispositivo que te interesa.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Funciona. Muchas gracias mi muy distinguido amigo.